# What benefits does IOC provide over soft-coding?

Tags: dependency-injection

Take the following article for example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2009/11/23/use-dependency-injection-to-simplify-application-settings.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+dotnetmvp+%28Patrick+Steele%27s+.NET+Blog%29

I don't see what benefit there is from the IOC approach as opposed to the traditional soft-coding approach. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article itself pretty much answers your question:

> During production, dependency injection takes over and automatically gives me my `AppConfigSettings` instance. For testing, I generate a mock `IApplicationSettings`.

Generally speaking, design patterns, practices and approaches (IoC is not much a pattern) try to help you at least one thing: minimize [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)) and maxmize [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). When you're directly using `ConfigurationManager` and all that (`Convert.ToBoolean`, etc) you are:

- Coupling your code to `ConfigurationManager` (bad for testing and reuse)
- Coupling your code to the configuration file itself (there's no other way to configure your class other than through `.config` file; bad for testing and reuse as well)
- Mixing responsibilities (reading and parsing configuration settings; violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))

Granted, using IoC *only* for reading configuration settings is an overkill, but surely this post deals only with a small part of a much bigger picture.

Comment: You are correct Anton.  I wasn't advocating IoC only for configuration settings.  As JacobM said, if you're already using IoC, here's another place where it can come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

For that particular application of IoC, it means you don't have to know the string keys everywhere you use the settings, just where you read them.

It also means the `Foo` class can be given application settings that came from somewhere other than the configuration file. This is useful for unit-testing, or for one-off instances of `Foo` which need settings other than those defined in the configuration file.

A good question to ask might be: should `Foo` know how to read configuration settings *and* use them?

Answer (score 0):

In that particular article, Patrick decouples the Foo class' direct dependency on the config file, it's structure etc. By implementing an interface to those settings and then passing them from the outside to the Foo class, Foo gets what it needs, runs as it should but is no longer dependent on the config file only. Foo doesn't care where the settings come from.

These concepts are called decoupling and dependency injection and help to create much more manageable, and per Patrick's example, more testable code.

Answer (score 0):

IoC gives you truly independent reusable components, rather than just a configurable monolithic system. Monolithic systems are harder to maintain because everything is interdependent.  Componentized systems are easier to reason about, test and change because you can use each part in isolation.

Inversion of control means that individual components only access each other through abstractions and have no say in how they are wired together. If you read about components in the [UML spec](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/formal/uml.htm) (superstructure specification Chapter 8), then it is obvious that the concepts of IoC and "component" must always go hand in hand:

> An important aspect of component-based
>   development is the reuse of previously
>   constructed components. A component
>   can always be considered an autonomous
>   unit within a system or subsystem. It
>   has one or more provided and/or
>   required interfaces (potentially
>   exposed via ports), and its internals
>   are hidden and inaccessible other than
>   as provided by its interfaces.
>   Although it may be dependent on other
>   elements in terms of interfaces that
>   are required, a component is
>   encapsulated and its dependencies are
>   designed such that it can be treated
>   as independently as possible. As a
>   result, components and subsystems can
>   be flexibly reused and replaced by
>   connecting (“wiring”) them together
>   via their provided and required
>   interfaces. The aspects of autonomy
>   and reuse also extend to components at
>   deployment time. The artifacts that
>   implement component are intended to be
>   capable of being deployed and
>   re-deployed independently, for
>   instance to update an existing system.